# HD Projectors 1920x1080 native Resolution 120 inch screen

Tags: projector

I want to buy an LED projector.

It must support HDMI input. 1920x1080. I want to play video games at that.

It must support large screen size with 120 inch a minimum.

Sound is optional because I will have my own speaker. 3D is very optional.

I will use it to watch movie, play games, and yes work. I like to work at big TV.

Price range is between 500-2000 USD. I know Acer [H6510BD] is good enough and meet the spec. I want to know if there is anything even better.

One of the thing I consider is [Acer H6510BD 3D Home Theater Projector](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B97ZKIA).

I am willing to pay extra for true 3D (I can play diablo with glasses). I want passive 3D.

3D is unnecessary. I prefer higher res thank 3D. I definitely do not want active 3D glasses. It seems that most 3D glasses for projectors are passive am I right?

I also want very long lamp life. I am going to use this projector for most of my waking hour. I work and play and watch movie at the same screen. Yap the screen will run windows.

I am currently comparing these projectors. None of them I like most because I really don't need that 3D feature. But hei, I might as well enjoy it.

1. [Benq-mw526](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MBE21DC) doesn't seem to have required resolution but show up in amazon if I search for 1920*1080
2. [Optoma GT7](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005G2HR6W) doesn't seem to have required resolution but show up in amazon if I search for 1920*1080
3. [Acer-H6510BD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B97ZKIA) my most preferred one
4. [BenQ MH680](http://www.projectorcentral.com/BenQ-MH680.htm)  second fav. what's the difference? more noisy?
5. [ViewSonic PJD7822](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BBM4A52)
6. [ViewSonic PJD7820HD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BBM0664)
7. [Mitsubishi HC3800](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002PIPPUK)

Comment: Please provide price range. So it will be easier to find something which meets rest of your requirements.

Comment: the 3D part is nice but it would be a waste. Most of the time I didn't do 3D thingy

Answer (score 1):

I finally bought 2 of them

http://www.projectorcentral.com/parts_compare.cfm?pid_1=7456&pid_2=7436

Well to be exact, I bought one. And then realize that the second one is better for me. So I exchange the first one with the second one.

Acer H6510BD http://www.projectorcentral.com/Acer-H6510BD.htm is the way to go.

However, my room has a width of 3.2 m and I want a REALLY BIG screen.

So I search for something similar but smaller throw radius.

So I exchange that with

BenQ W1080ST http://www.projectorcentral.com/BenQ-W1080ST.htm

More expensive. But I think I will be able to get a big 4 m wide TV I have always wanted to work peacefully.

Regular TV would have cost $5k and stuff. This projector only costs $1200.

Yes, the second one is more expensive. So it depends on where you want to put things. If you want to put it on a big room where you can afford some distance between the projector and the TV, then the first one is the way to go.

Note: I should have answered with something I recommend rather than actually bought. However, I finally bought... can be interpreted as I recommend .... I mean why would I buy something I don't think is good? Not sure how the mod would think.

Comment: Mark this as the answer if you're happy with your selection.

Comment: Should I give chance for others to make their answers? Hmmm... Feels like there is a conflict of interest given that I am the judge and I mark my own. Very well. No one else is answering anyway. Yes I like the one I bought and I did very extensive research before choosing this.